# Feature Class Geometry in Stored as 0 to 360 degrees, rather than -180 to 180 degrees

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, geometry

My X coordinates for my geometries are all stored in 0-360.  ArcMap seems to handle it fine (i.e. knows that 260°=-100°) except when I use python geometry methods.  The geometry methods (intersect, contains, etc.) don't function properly against other geometries in the same CRS, but with 180-base coordinates.   What causes the 360-based coordinates?  Is it something in the feature class, CRS, or must the actual coordinate values be adjusted?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you working with Alaska data at all?  It could be they did that to help deal with anti-meridian issues.

Comment: The data is not in Alaska, but I see that logic.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to detail the problems you are encountering. Latitude doesn't wrap the way longitude does, so your reference to Y values makes no sense at all.